# React Router 5 - How to define the route for specific page without header and side navigation bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a react application using react-router 5 and here is the screen flow in the attachment. I am quite confused to achieve the route as per the UI.

Basically, the application has 4 screen which starts with Login, gets into Student List(*List of items*), Student Info(*Particular student info in limited*) and Student Info(*Particular student info in detailed*)

```
- Login ('/') --> No header and side nav bar
 - Student List ('/students')--> Student Info('/student/01') - --> With header and side nav bar
 - Student Detailed Info ('/detail')- --> Without header and side nav bar(but not a modal window)
```

Screen Flow:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by structure of you routes...

```
<Route exact path="\">
 login screen
</Route>
<Route>
 <Header />
 <sidebar />
 <Switch>
  <Route path="students" />
  <Route path="info" />
  ...
 </Switch>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:
1 -

```
<Route path="students">
// Wrap the routes/pages with header and sidebar
</Route>
<Route path="detail">
// Wrap the routes/pages without header and sidebar
</Route>
```

2 - on header/sidebar components, detect the current route and skip these components rendering.